# how to download a file on disk with specific location using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

> i want to download a file automatically using javascript or jquery
>   below is the code which i am using but that code open the file in new
>   tab in browser not download in disk.

```
function SaveToDisk(fileUrl, fileName) {
    var hyperlink = document.createElement('a');
    hyperlink.href = fileUrl;
    hyperlink.target = '_blank';
    hyperlink.download = fileName || fileUrl;

    (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(hyperlink);
    hyperlink.onclick = function() {
       (document.body || document.documentElement).removeChild(hyperlink);
    };

    var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    });

    hyperlink.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);

    // NEVER use "revoeObjectURL" here
    // you can use it inside "onclick" handler, though.
    // (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(hyperlink.href);

    // if you're writing cross-browser function:
    if(!navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // i.e. if it is NOT Firefox
       window.URL.revokeObjectURL(hyperlink.href);
    }
}


        SaveToDisk('http://example.com/service/getUserImage/339/256', 'image.png');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `XMLHttpRequest()` to request file from server as a `Blob`,  utilize `URL.createObjectURL()`, `<a>` element with `download` attribute and `href` attribute set to `Blob URL`, then call `.click()` on `<a>` element.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://example.com/service/getUserImage/339/256");
request.responseType = "blob";
request.onload = function() {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
  a.download = this.response.name;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
}
request.send();
```

Comment: cn you please tell me how

Comment: not working while get method response is null and nothing happend

Comment: @SumitAggarwal _"not working while get method response is null and nothing happend"_  What does `console.log(this.response)` log? Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: @SumitAggarwal Yes, can you include the `html` and `javascript` that you used to reproduce _"not working while get method response is null and nothing happend"_ at http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview , click `Save` and share saved plnkr?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118869/discussion-between-sumit-aggarwal-and-guest271314).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118888/discussion-between-sumit-aggarwal-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

Create a hidden link when the ajax is complete with a attribute of download,trigger a click event on that link

```
$('body').append('<a class="hidden-ajax" download href="'+url+'"></a>')
$('.hidden-ajax').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
function(url){
   window.href(url);
}
```

Comment: your code is opening the file in the browser. I want to download it on my disk space automatically because there is no click button

Comment: window.open(url) opens on newtab nu widow.href(url) download it.

Comment: sorry use window.location.href

Comment: I have no idea why anyone ever upvoted this. It's completely wrong: href isn't a property of window, and `location.href` isn't a function, and assigning to `location.href` just does the same thing as navigating to it normally.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count=0;
$('#testdownload').on('click', function(){
count++;
$('#log').append('<li>Click triggered ' + count + ' times</li>');
});

$('#testdownload').get(0).click();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Fkb5/9/)

Comment: i have no clicklable thing

Comment: Yes I got this so every page refresh it will download your doct.

Comment: Are you want mouse event for this or what?

Comment: i dont want any event, i have already function calling other tak in between that function i need to download the file in desktop automatically without user interference

Comment: Okay so use $('#testdownload').get(0).click(); as I suggested it will download your file just you entered in to the page.

Comment: i don't underrstand where this code get the url of the file?

Comment: See simple there is a href link with "id" so I simple pass that id to jquery. check this demo.

Comment: as i told you earlier i have no href tag or a tag. i have a url which i need to download ocally with specific location